# Validación de formularios con Ajax y jQuery para no enviar formulario vacio

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

mi formulario lo envió por medio de ajax y por tal motivo cancelo la propiedad de submit el cual ya no me deja usar required propio de html mi pregunta es como puedo validar que ningún campo este vació y una vez que estos sean validados enviar mi petición por ajax.

asi envio mi formulario:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnguardar').click(function(){
      var datos=$('#frmajax').serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"scripts/reg_vehiculo.php",
        data:datos,
        success:function(r){

          if(r==1){
            alert("Fallo al agregar");
          }else{
            alert("Vehiculo agregado con éxito!!");
            document.getElementById("frmajax").reset();
          }
        }
      });

      return false;
    });
  });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con esto

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#btnguardar').click(function(){
            if($('#idInput1').val() !=""){
               var datos=$('#frmajax').serialize();
               $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  url:"scripts/reg_vehiculo.php",
                  data:datos,
                  success:function(r){
                     if(r==1){
                        alert("Fallo al agregar");
                     }else{
                        alert("Vehiculo agregado con éxito!!");
                        document.getElementById("frmajax").reset();
                     }
                  }
               });
            } else {
               alert('campos vacíos');
            }
            return false;
         });
      });
   </script>
```

Comment: ya lo intente pero no funciona

Comment: ¿cambiaste el idInput1 por el nombre d tu id del input?

Comment: no había visto lo del input perdón, ya funciono se tendría que poner if($('#idInput1').val() !="") para cada input de mi formulario

Comment: solamente un if seria if($('#idInput1').val() !="" && $('#idInput2').val() !="" && etc.){//codigo }

Comment: ok perfecto si me funciono tu código pero eso de mandar el alert no me gusto mas bien tendría que buscar como poner un mensaje debajo de cada input con un texto que diga que falta llenar ese campo

Comment: ese alert solamente era para corroborar que funciona el método de ahi es tu creatvidad ver de que manera presentar la información, saludos

Comment: ok muchas gracias por tu apoyo